# Linux Script not Running Upon Reboot

Tags: ruby, bash, api, raspbian, slack

I know, I know. These posts appear *all* the dang time. I swear, my machine/code is an exception to what most people are trying to accomplish/what problem(s) they're running into when attempting to set up these seemingly simple scripts.

I have a file named `IPdetermination.rb` on my Raspberry Pi (running the Raspbian OS) that basically uses the `rest-client` ruby gem to perform a http POST with JSON. Such is the code:

```
#sends a message to slack using incoming-webhook that identifies that
#host machine's name and ip address.
require 'rest-client'
address = Socket.ip_address_list.detect {|x| x.ipv4_private?}.ip_address
name = Socket.gethostname
if name.include? '.' then name = name.slice(0..name.index('.') - 1) end
payload = {text: "*Device:* `#{name}`\n *IP:* `#{address}`"}.to_json
RestClient.post 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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', payload
```

Note that this *does* work. So, in fact, does this bash script, which is stored under `/etc/init.d`

```
#! /bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/ip_addr

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          ip_addr
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: ip address locator
# Description:       sends hostname's ip address on private slack channel
### END INIT INFO
exec ruby ~/Documents/coding/ruby/IPdetermination.rb
exit 0
```

They both work when manually executed, successfully posting a message on Slack. Note that I have both attached LSB comments to the `ip_addr` script and configured the file such so that running `ls -l` returns `-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root  413 Dec 30 03:39 ip_addr`. Running `chkconfig --list` correctly displays `ip_addr  0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off`.

**Yet**

It doesn't work! Rebooting the system does not seem to run the script. My only theory could be that the POSTing could be faulty upon reboot, yet I cannot determine whether or not this is the source of the problem. What do I do?

Edit: Changing the `Required-Start:` and `Required-Stop:` to also include the boot facilities `$network` and `$named` did not work either.

Comment: Have you enabled that service file?

Comment: @cricket_007 do you mean via the `update-rc.d` command? I have done that.

Comment: What's happen if the file names (ruby and IPdetermination.rb) on the bash script change to full path names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally found the problem, thanks to users like @tasasaki. What happened was I added a line within `/etc/rc.local` that called my bash script with a **full** path name, as well as editing the bash script to have **full** path names. Also, within `rc.local`, I didn't realize `exit 0` is only put down once, so I put my code after the `exit 0`. Moving it up probably helped as well. Should anyone find this, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

afaik scripts under /etc/init.d/ are not executed upon reboot. there need to be at least symbolic links set in the runlevel directories `/etc/rc*.d/` prefixed with an `S` if you want to run a script upon boot when entering the specific runlevel. if prefixed with `K` it means something like kill so it won't be executed upon boot or gets killed on shutdown. numerical values appended to these main prefix let you define an order in which the scripts are run on boot.

so if you want to run `ascript` on boot when entering run level two you need to do sth like:

```
$ ln -s /etc/init.d/ascript /etc/rc2.d/S01ascript
```

this will cause ascript to be run first when entering runlevel 2.
any update mechanism like `update-rc.d` or `systemctl enable ...` will just set such links to make scripts avaiable/called on boot.

hope this helps. regards

Comment: There are already symlinks in each of the rc*.d folders for the run levels i set ip_addr to work in. Changing `S02ip_addr` (what it was) to `S100ip_addr` also did not work.